# Удаление строки из текстового файла в программе на java swing

Tags: java, swing, listener

Есть у меня программа типа словаря, в которой есть кнопка удалить. Задача такая, мне нужно найти строку в текстовом файле, и удалить её. Находить, я нахожу, но вот удалять строку я не научился. Пробовал такой вот метод

```
private void DeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
     String filePath = "Dictio.txt";
     String outputLine = jTextField3.getText();
     String line=null;     
     jTextField3.setText(" ");
     try {
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Dictio.txt")));
         BufferedWriter out1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Dictio.txt")));
         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                 if(line.contains(outputLine)){
                   out1.newLine();
                   out1.write(""); 
                   out1.close();
                 }
             }
          // закрываем
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println("Error in file cleaning: " + e.getMessage());
         }    
    }
```

Но получается пока удалять все содержимое из файла, а надо только заранее найденную строку.

Answer (score 3):

В приведённом Вами коде присутствует сразу несколько грубейших ошибок:

- Вы записываете данные сразу в тот же файл из которого их только что прочитали;
- Вы записываете в файл пустую строку;
- После записи первой строки Вы сразу же закрываете файл.

В итоге получается описанный Вами результат.

Чтобы этого не было:

1. Создаём две файловые переменные.

   `File sourceFile = new File("Dictio.txt");
    File outputFile = new File("Dictio2.txt");`
2. Записываем в новый файл все данные, кроме удаляемой строки.

   `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.equals(outputLine)) {
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        }
    }`
3. Затем удаляем исходный файл, а получившийся файл переименовываем.

   `reader.close();
    writer.close();
    sourceFile.delete();
    outputFile.renameTo(sourceFile);`

**P.S.**

В данной ситуации, ИМХО, более рациональным решением было бы прочитать файл в строковый массив, а затем удалить в нём нужную строку и перезаписать исходный файл с новыми данными.

Comment: Тут есть какая то ошибка. Срабатывает IOException.

Comment: Ошибок нет. Алгоритм рабочий. Судя по всему, что-то сделали не так. Просто, нужно хотя бы немного разобраться, а не копировать в свой проект "в лоб". Без обид. Выкладывайте код, как пытались применить решение из ответа, и stack trace исключения. Комментарии из категории "у меня не получается и всё" здесь не прокатывают.

Comment: Как вставлять код в комментарии я не знаю (F.A.Q. показанный внизу я не понял). Но делал примерно так, сначала задал outputLine так, как задал его в своем первоначальном варианте. Затем объявил переменную таким образом- String line; . Потом объявил два файла как указанно у вас в примере. Основную часть с записью в файл кроме удаляемой строки я окружил try/catch. И в этом же блоке перед самым catch задал удаление исходного и переименовывание нового файла. И исключение выглядит так java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: outputFile - скорее всего надо создать =)

Comment: java.io.File.createNewFile()

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, файл корректно создаётся и без `createNewFile`. Проходил по алгоритму отладчиком "в разных вариантах". Ошибка ТС не воспроизводится (честно).

Comment: outputFile как раз создается, с этим все нормально. Но вроде как он должен удалятся после выполнения программы, а он остается, и остается пустым. Мне кажется что где то есть проблема записи в этот самый новый файл.

Comment: @Strelez Я так же пробовал проходить по алгоритму в разных вариантах, и во всех случаях получал Exception. Не знаю играет это какую то роль или нет, но программа пишется на NetBeans

Comment: @OrlyI, он как раз не должен удаляться. Его необходимо **переименовать**. Что собственно и делается в примере. Также советую проверить поток записи в этот файл на "закрытие".

Comment: @Strelez Очень странно, но сейчас я получаю просто два одинаковых текстовых файла. Очевидно что не работает функция удаления строки. Переставил ваш 3-й пункт, sourceFile.delete(); поставил в конец перед catch.

Comment: @OrlyI, "пункты" должны идти так, как приведено в ответе. И 3й шаг алгоритма включает не только удаление исходного файла.

Comment: @OrlyI, не обижайтесь, но всё это лишь подтверждает то, о чём я говорил в самом начале. Вы не разбираясь скопировали решение в лоб. Причем, вероятно, даже не полностью, а частично. После этого пытаетесь заставить проект работать методом "научного тыка". Так что ничего здесь странного нет. В ответе решение дано практически в готовом виде. Нужно просто совсем чуть-чуть вникнуть. Попробуйте сравнить как выполняются одни и те же действия в Вашем исходном примере и в моём ответе.

Comment: @Strelez Хотите верьте, а хотите нет, но ваш код я внимательно разбирал прежде чем копировать. И по идее он должен выглядеть так: 1-ая часть объявляется вместе с переменной outputLine и String line;. Потом пишем try и открываем фигурную скобку, в ней пишем часть-2, далее когда закрывается фигурная скобка за while я вставил 3-ю часть. Потом закрыл блок try и написал catch с IOException. И так оно вроде должно работать, но вместо этого получаю 2 файла с одинаковым текстом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40095/discussion-between-streletz-and-orlyi).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            RandomAccessFile fr = new RandomAccessFile("/sdcard/playlist/rate.lst", "r");
            String line;
            String needline="Hello"; //это будет первой строкой
            StringBuffer sbt=new StringBuffer("");
            while ((line = fr.readLine()) != null){
                //if line==bobo{
                //  os.abort()
                //}
                //else{
                //  no.abort()
                //}
                sbt.append(line+"\n");
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/sdcard/playlist/rate.lst");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(needline+"\n"+ sbt.toString());
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            fr.close();
            System.out.println("");

            //в цикле while с помощью конструкции if else операции с
            //читаемыми строками: с помощью сравнения строк(comparetoignore) - пропуск(удаление) любой строки, замена любой строки.
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как код в ответе выравнивать?

Comment: Перед строкой кода должно быть четыре пробела.

Answer (score 0):

Этот код удаляет строки начинающиеся со слова "hello".

```
    Path input = Paths.get("file.txt");
    Path temp = Files.createTempFile("temp", ".txt");
    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(input);
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(temp)) {
        lines
                .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("hello"))
                .forEach(line -> {
                    try {
                        writer.write(line);
                        writer.newLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });
    }

    Files.move(temp, input, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```